# Javascript Solution to clean up CSS

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am working on adding some CSS to a site I am making, and have identified what I need to modify:

```
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1{
background-color: #FFF !important;
outline: 4px solid white;
}
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2{
background-color: #FFF !important;
outline: 4px solid white;
}
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3{
background-color: #FFF !important;
outline: 4px solid white;
}
```

.....

```
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ20{
background-color: #FFF !important;
outline: 4px solid white;
}
```

I can't override the upper level more generic containers so that it doesn't require the different numbers. Is there a JS or other solution to my problem? I don't have the ability to edit the HTML, only the CSS.

*I didn't see a similar question but I may just be using the wrong terms.*

Comment: Well normally one would use a class. Without seeing HTML hard to give you solutions that do not rely on ID.

Comment: @epascarello updating OP but I lack the ability to edit the HTML on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution use a class or a selector that targets the element without using the id, but you can use an attribute starts with [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
[id^="foo"] {
    background-color: green;
    margin: .2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo1">foo1</div>
<div id="foo2">foo2</div>
<div id="foo3">foo3</div>
<div id="foo4">foo4</div>
<div id="5foo">5foo</div>
<div id="6foo6">6foo6</div>
```

Comment: To clarify, [id^="foo"] will allow cause an edit on any id that starts with "foo" to receive that edit?

Comment: any id that starts with foo gets those css rules.